# Visa for travelling to France, as UK residents on SA passports

Tags: visas, france, spain, south-african-citizens

Good afternoon,

We are South Africans with SA Passports living in the UK on an ancestral visa - how do we go about visiting France / Spain?   Do we need separate visa on entering either France / Spain?

My husband has an ancestral visa and I have a spousal ancestral visa.

Answer (score 4):

Both of you need a Schengen visa, which will allow you to travel to both France and Spain. You should apply to either of those countries, depending on where you will spend the most time. If you plan to stay about the same time in each, you should apply to the country you will enter first.

The UK visa is only relevant to the extent that it allows you to apply for the Schengen visa in the UK and that it might help alleviate concerns that you might seek to immigrate illegally, thus making the Schengen visa slightly easier to obtain than if you were living in South Africa.